# spam honeypot api

Tags: api, email, email-spam, honeypot

I would like to know if there is a mail spam honeypot api arround allowing the users to fetch the actual emails content.

Comment: you mean http://getpopfile.org ?
What I'm looking for is a service allowing me to download "spam emails" in order to do some datamining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need spam emails to datamine with, then you're better off finding a [spam corpus](http://www.google.com/search?hl=sv&client=safari&rls=sv-se&q=spam+email+corpus&btnG=S%C3%B6k&lr=) (google link).  The [top site](http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~gvcormac/treccorpus/) offers a downloadable zipfile with plenty of spams to cut your teeth on.